# How to change text widget title h2 to h1

Tags: widgets, widget-text

I created text widget and wordpress created some default styles it uses h2 tag and class "widgettitle". How can i change tag to h1 and remove class from it.

This is my function.php file

```
function home_consultation_init() {
    register_sidebar(array(
        "name" => "Home Consulatation",
        "id" => "home_consult",
        "before_widget" => "",
        "after_widget" => "",
        "before-title" => "",
        "after-title" => ""
    ));
}
```

Comment: You already have `before-title` and `after-title` parameters to achieve your goal. See [`register_sidebar()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar) in the Codex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `before-title` and `after-title` arguments passed to `register_sidebar()` need to use underscores:

```
register_sidebar(array(
    "name" => "Home Consulatation",
    "id" => "home_consult",
    "before_widget" => "",
    "after_widget" => "",
    "before_title" => "",
    "after_title" => ""
));
```

If you use that the titles won't have any tags. You need to provide them to the `before_title` and `after_title` arguments, like so:

```
register_sidebar(array(
    "name" => "Home Consulatation",
    "id" => "home_consult",
    "before_widget" => "",
    "after_widget" => "",
    "before_title" => "<h1>",
    "after_title" => "</h1>"
));
```

Your problem was that you were using the incorrect keys (with `-` instead of `_`), so it was using the defaults.

Answer (score 1):

widget title h2 to h1 change you have change in **where you register widgets**. two arguments "before_title" and "after_title".

```
register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => esc_html__( 'Sidebar', 'themeName' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => '',
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h1>',
    ) );
```